# In her second boon, why does Kaikeyi say नव पञ्च च वर्षाणि (nine and five years) instead of चतुर्दश वर्षाणि (fourteen years)?

Tags: ramayana, rama, valmiki, kaikeyi

Revealing her second boon to Daśaratha, Kaikeyī [says](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga11/ayodhyasans11.htm#Verse26) "नव पञ्च च वर्षाणि" (nine and five years) instead of चतुर्दश वर्षाणि (fourteen years). Is this just Vālmīki's play of words or is there a deeper significance to it?

> **नव पञ्च च वर्षाणि** दण्डकारण्यमाश्रितः || २-११-२६ 
> चीराजिनजटाधारी रामो भवतु तापसः |
>
> 26.
> raamaH = Rama; aashritaH = has to take refuge; daNdakaaranyam = in the forest of Dandaka; **nava paJNcha cha varshhaNi** = for fourteen years; bhavatu taapasaH = let him become ascetic; chiiraajiina jataadhaarii = wearing rags; deer skin and matted hair.
>
> "Rama has to take refuge in the forest of Dandaka **for fourteen years** and let him become an ascetic wearing rags, deer skin and matted hair".

Comment: I think this is just to maintain Chhanda.. however there is a possibility that it has some deeper significance.. if one writes चतुर्दश वर्षाणी there will be only 15 letters.. but 16 letters are needed to complete that Chhanda...

Comment: @Tezz There must be some significance attached, because Rama uses "Caturdasa Hi Varsani' to complete the 16 syllables. Similarly Kaikeyi could have used 'Caturdasa Ca/Hi/Tu/Eva Varsani', but instead Valmiki says Nava Pancha, which means there is something more to it. @ sv Nice question.

Comment: @sv. Because 14 years forest exile was considered as a punishment for severe crimes or sins in those days. By using नव पञ्च च वर्षाणि instead of चतुर्दश वर्षाणि kaikeyi only meant an exile away from the throne but not as a punishment. Because she also  knew the greatness and blemishlessness of Rama.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yeah, I heard something like that recently in Chaganti's speech. Looking for some references.

Comment: @sv. I commented above after listening to his discourses.

Comment: @SreeCharan Ok, maybe you can write an answer then.

Comment: Well, i have seen that exile in forest for 12 years is a punishment for one of the severe sins..but not 14 years..

Comment: @Rickross It differs with yuga. That's why Pandavas got 12 years exile in dwapara.

Comment: @SreeCharan I have checked in Manu Smriti (which was the only Dharma Shastra in Krita)only,which says 12 years exile in forest is one of the punishments for one of the grave sins..Can u post scriptural references about this 14 years thing?I was unable to find..

Comment: @Rickross I heard it in a discourse by a knowledgeable person. I don't have scriptural reference for that. So didn't post as an answer.

Comment: @SreeCharan Ok.then it must be true...Actually i searched Manu Smriti..but cud find only the 12 year punishment....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just to maintain the writing style. These **synonymous words** are used in Ramayana for the same:

> नव प़ञ्च च वर्षाणि (9+5)
>
> नव वर्षाणि पञ्च च (9+5)
>
> सप्त सप्त च वर्षाणि (7+7)
>
> वर्षाणीह चतुर्दश (14)
>
> चतुर्दश हि वर्षाणि (14)
>
> षट्चाष्टौ च वर्षाणि (6+8)

**Kaikayi to Dashratha (2.11.26) :**

> **नव प़ञ्च च वर्षाणि** दण्डकारण्यमाश्रितः।
> चीराजिनजटाधारी रामो भवतु तापसः।।

**Kaikayi to Lord Shri Rama (2.18.35) :**

> सन्निदेशे पितुस्तिष्ठ यथा तेन प्रतिश्रुतम्।
> त्वयाऽरण्यं प्रवेष्टव्यं **नव वर्षाणि पञ्च च**।।

**Kaikayi to Lord Shri Rama (2.18.37) :**

> **सप्त सप्त च वर्षाणि** दण्डकारण्यमाश्रितः।
> अभिषेकमिमं त्यक्त्वा जटाजिनधरो वस।।

**Lord Shri Rama to Kaikayi (2.19.23) :**

> अनुक्तोऽप्यत्रभवता भवत्या वचनादहम्।
> वने वत्स्यामि विजने **वर्षाणीह चतुर्दश**।।

**Lord Shri Rama to Kausalya (2.20.29) :**

> **चतुर्दश हि वर्षाणि** वत्स्यामि विजने वने।
> मधुमूलफलैर्जीवन्हित्वा मुनिवदामिषम्।।

**Lord Shri Rama to Kausalya (2.20.31) :**

> स **षट्चाष्टौ च वर्षाणि** वत्स्यामि विजने वने।
> आसेवमानो वन्यानि फलमूलैश्च वर्तयन्।।